# 'module' object has no attribute 'shortcuts'

Tags: django

In my Django app's view, I have a method for registration, in which I am trying to render output using a template. The program compiled fine and the server ran without any problems, when I tried to access the register from a browser it is throwing exception claiming 'module' object has no attribute 'shortcuts' . May I know what i am doing wrong here.

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse
from commons import Commons
from djangolearn.models import UserExtForm
from djangolearn.models import UserForm
import django


def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello world")

def register(request):
  uform = UserForm(prefix='user')
  uxtform = UserExtForm(prefix='userprofile')
  cont = dict(userform=uform,userprofileform=uxtform)
  return django.shortcuts.render(request, 'register.html', cont)
```

Templates settings from settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['D:/projects/eclipse/djangolearn/djangolearn/templates',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly import render or shortcuts because it is a helper function and [django.shortcuts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#module-django.shortcuts) is package.

```
from django import shortcuts
from django.shortcuts import render
```